# Can't get a regex to handle brackets properly

Tags: python, regex

Apologies for the vague title.

I'm trying to get a regex that searches and OKs something like this:

> "Brand New Song [Demonstration]"

by finding the "[Demonstration]" somewhere in the string, using `re.search()`. Here's an example of what I think *should* return True:

```
bool (re.search (r"\b\[Demonstration\]\b", "Brand New Song [demonstration]", re.IGNORECASE))
```

Going even simpler, this also returns False:

```
bool (re.search (r"\b\[\b", " [ "))
```

I've been using `\b` for the beginning and ends of captured string because it's supposed to represent any empty space string at the beginning or end of a word ([as per documentation here)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), and I don't see what I'm messing up.

Continuing befuddlement, the following returns True:

```
bool (re.search (r"\b\[\b", "_[_"))
```

which is equally confusing because `\b` is **defined** partly as *"...whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character."* So, please help me find what stupid detail I'm likely missing, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the word boundaries `\b` from your pattern.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Brand New Song [demonstration]'
>>> bool(re.search (r'\[Demonstration\]', s, re.IGNORECASE))
True
```

A word boundary does not consume any characters, it asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not. As stated in the [regular-expressions.info **documentation**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> > - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> > - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> > - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Comment: I had no idea that was how they operated. How would I handle having whitespace OR nothing on the outside of a square bracket set? So that "This is a [test]" would be true but "This [should]be False" would be False?

Comment: You could use a non-word boundary `\B` or use lookaround assertions. i.e `(?<!\S)\[[^]]*\](?!\S)`